# symfony2.0.0 get locale in security.yml

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.0

I'm using symfony2.0.0. I don't have a chance to update symfony.
This is my security.yml

```
firewalls:
        main:
          logout: true
          pattern: .*
          http_basic: true
          anonymous: true
          form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: /login
            use_forward:  true
            check_path: /login_check
            failure_path: /login_fail
          remember_me:
            key:      "lkjxd%34(lksdf;SDfsf"
            lifetime: 31536000
            path:     /
            domain:   ~
```

How can I use locale for my **failure_path**. Tried to use /%locaale%/failure_path but it  always return en(my default locale). It does not understand route names. If I use the name of the route e.g. **login_fail** it does not work(redirecting like a relative path).

This is my route.

```
login_fail:
  pattern: /{_locale}/login_fail
  defaults: { _controller: ContactbeeProfileBundle:Profile:dashboard, _locale: en }
```

Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: I have this issue also in symfony 3.0, any solutions?

Comment: I was long time ago. But as I remember the very first answer below has solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration is loaded before DIC is compiled before the request is actually processed, as it's accessible from `Request`, **you can't access locale in configuration**.

If you don't mind one extra redirect, you can have an action that will redirect user after failed authentication to correct route:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class SecurityController extends Controller {
    public function failedAction() {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login_fail_localized'), [
            'locale' => $this->getRequest()->getLocale()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Set failure path to match it's route:

```
# routing.yml
login_fail:
    pattern: /login_fail
        defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Security:failed }

login_fail_localized:
    pattern: /{locale}/login_fail
        defaults: { _controller: ContactbeeProfileBundle:Profile:dashboard }
```

Comment: Thanks man. I've used all routes with the prefix:{locale}/. That's why i was getting locale=login_fail. Your idea is good and simple. Thanks.But it's strange that I cann't use the route names in security.yml. Maybe it's because of my version 2.0.0))